# Picture is not uploading in firebase storage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I make sign up, sign in authentication and I want to upload user picture in firebase and retrieve user pic when its login and show in navbar but my picture is not uploading on firebase storage and don't showing me any error...
I try firebase storage to upload pic in firebase I import all the firebase app, AUTH

```js
  
     
  import { getStorage, ref, uploadString } from "firebase/storage";
             
            ///////////////            variables           //////////////////
                var ImgName,ImgUrl;
                var files = [];
                var reader;
                // Your web app's Firebase configuration
                const firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyBkOCUfUZMWvjOHW42cbHpLqsnVUj5Q-Oc",
                authDomain: "sign-in-up-32ddf.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://sign-in-up-32ddf-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "sign-in-up-32ddf",
                storageBucket: "sign-in-up-32ddf.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "249984840278",
                appId: "1:249984840278:web:b6b9eb4737cebb7d9601f7"
                };
            
                // Initialize Firebase
                 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
               firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    //  //................................ selection Processssssss .......................//
              document.getElementById("select").onclick = function(e){
               
                 var input = document.createElement('input');
                 input.type = 'file';
                 input.click();
                
                 input.onchange =e=>{
                     files = e.target.files;
                     reader = new FileReader();
                     reader.onload = function(){
                         document.getElementById("myimg").src = reader.result;
                     }
                     reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
                 }
                 input.click();
              }
 
              /////................upload img Processsss..................///////////////////

            
               
              document.getElementById("upload").onclick = function(e){
                
                    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
                    console.log("profileeeeeeeeee");

                ImgName = document.getElementById('namebox').value;
                   var uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref('Images/'+ImgName+".png").put(files[0]);
 
                    uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
                         var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
                         document.getElementById('upProgress').innerHTML='Upload'+progress+'%';
                    },
                     function(error){
                         alert('error in saving the image');
                     },
                      //.............................submit image link to database.....................//
                     function(){
                         uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
                                 ImgUrl = url;
                                
 
                         firebase.database().ref('Pictures/'+ImgName).set({
                             Name: ImgName,
                             Link:ImgUrl
 
                         });
                         alert('image added successfully');
                     }
                    );
                 });
              }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <title>
        <h1>Prooofile</h1>
    </title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

 </head>
 <body>
    <style> img{height: 100px;width: 100px;border-style: 2px solid black;}</style>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>picccccccc page</h1>
        Image Name <input id="namebox" type="text"><br><br>
        

        <img id="myimg"><label id="upProgress"></label> <br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="select" value="select" />
  <input type="submit" id="upload" value="upload" />
        <button id="select">select img</button>
        <button id="upload">Upload img</button>
        <button id="retrieve">retrieve img</button>

    </div>
    
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
         <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
         <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
         <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
   </body>
</html>
```

, storage and database links. Then I insert all connecting links in my code. I make changes in firebase storage rules according to my need but its not working.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that here isn't an error? Did you check your security rules?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting??, Do some print statements to determine which code breaks?